# Discrete Event Scheduling in NetLogo: Executing some command on some specific tick

Tags: netlogo

My code has one condition:

```
    if ticks = 10^7 [ do-something ]
```

Now this condition is checked on every ticks though I know exactly when I have to execute the command. This might be slowing my code. The [time extension](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time) does exactly this by time:go command. My command using time extension is:

```
     time:schedule-event patches task do-something 1000000
```

But this throwing an error:

```
Extension exception: Attempted to schedule an event for tick 999999.0 which is before the present 'moment' of 1000000.0
error while observer running TIME:SCHEDULE-EVENT
   called by procedure GO
   called by Button 'go'
```

Is there something I am missing? Or any other efficient way to schedule some event at specific tick without checking the ticks condition every tick?

Comment: Not sure what's going on with your `time` extension command (we'd need to see more code to debug it, I think), but there is one thing I can tell you: don't worry about the performance cost of a command like `if ticks = 10^7 [ do-something ]`. It's basically instantaneous.

Comment: If you're worried about the performance of your model, use the [`profiler`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html) extension; it will tell you where the real bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this looks like a bug in the time extension, please post it at https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/issues
and tell us where we can find your code. (Or email it to me.)