# Scheduling events with Netlogo time extension - ongoing bug with model running before scheduled event?

Tags: time, netlogo, scheduling

trying to run a scheduled event with the time extension. Procedure happens with patients/turtles entering at slow rate then rate increases for a few hours before returning. Can't get past this error:

```
Extension exception: Attempted to schedule an event for tick 168.0 which is
        before the present 'moment' of 219.00864034561383
error while patch -10 -10 running TIME:SCHEDULE-REPEATING-EVENT-WITH-PERIOD
```

to even test the rest of it. I found someone with the same problem 3 yrs ago but no fix or update found either here or GitHub.

[Discrete Event Scheduling in NetLogo: Executing some command on some specific tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41894275/discrete-event-scheduling-in-netlogo-executing-some-command-on-some-specific-ti)

Anyone have another source for problem-solving this one or is there another question/answers addressing this? If not I'll post on the GitHub page for creator advice.

```
to patients-arrive

ask patch -10 -10
    
     [sprout-patients random-poisson  0.0000001                       
     [set shape "person"                                                               
      set time_arrived ticks
      set condition random-float 1.0
      set los 0
      set complete? false
      move-to one-of arrivals
  ]]
                                                                             
  
time:schedule-repeating-event-with-period patch -10 -10 [                            
    [] ->  
   sprout-patients random-poisson   0.1                               
  [set shape "person"                                                                 
   set time_arrived ticks
   set condition random-float 1.0
   set los 0
   set complete? false
   move-to one-of arrivals
  ]]
   peak-start 24.0 "hours"
 time:go-until time:plus tick-datetime 6.0 "hour" 

end
```

peak-start is set at 168 ticks

Comment: ps the GitHub reference suggest the time:is-after primitive to overcome this but doesn't give an example. I'm asking for the rate of turtle creation to increase for 6hrs from 14:00hrs everyday

Answer (score 0):

was looking up another time extension feature and and found a very helpful comment from Railsback to the effect that current versions of Netlogo (version 6) are not compatible with scheduling events. so that solves that I guess.

if I hear there is compatibility I will post again